# How to get max value of a column for a second column

Tags: mysql

I have this code which produces the following result but I want to get the `week_day` for every customer with highest count. So instead of two or more rows with `customer_id`, I want one row with `week_day` with highest count for each `customer_id`.

SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT `sales_flat_order`.`customer_id`, 
  dayname(created_at) AS `week_day`, 
  COUNT(*) AS `cnt` 
FROM `sales_flat_order` 
group by week_day, `sales_flat_order`.`customer_id` 
order by cnt DESC
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why the output you already have is not the answer? Please provide an example of what the output should look like.

Comment: The output is more of half of the answer. Lets take an example of customer_id = 143. This customer has two rows. One row with week_day Tuesday and count 2; second row with week_day Wednesday and count 1. I would like to only one row for this customer_id with maximum count value.

Comment: Kindly provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements and some DML (INSERT INTO sales_flat_order VALUES(...)). Also. provide your desired result and the logic you used to get it. If there is a lot of data, you can use SQLFiddle or even PasteBin or similar.

Comment: I think he wants one row per customer.  That is a "groupwise-max".  Search for that; it is a common question, sometimes there is a valid answer.